# Background tasks, if users are on the website

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I have a bit of an issue here. Actually, it might not be an issue, I just don't really know how to handle it.

I need to copy an image, from a remote server, to my local server, every n seconds, IF (any) users are on my webpage.
If no users are on, it doesn't matter. If multiple users are on, it should only run the copy once (every n seconds).

I think I have heard somewhere, that you can do background tasks, on your ASP.NET website, but I have absolutely no knowledge of this. Some people also talk about threads, is it perhaps the same solution?

So, I'm hoping for some experienced people, to guide me towards a solution here. What possibilities do I have, which would you recommend and perhaps some articles where I can read how to do it.

Comment: It *can* be done, but multi-threaded programming is complex and notoriously error-prone. There is almost certainly a better way to do what you want (e.g. Lazy initilization, caching, etc.). Can you explain the background of the problem - i.e. what are you trying to achieve and why?

Comment: I need to copy an image from an ip-Web cam, and feed it to our users. Basically, we cannot have everyone connecting to the webcam, so i need to make a page that shows it, ón our intranet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your answer in the comments I would suggest you need to use a cache that supports time-based expiry.

See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/51409/Exploring-Caching-Using-Caching-Application-Enterp#heading0020 for a good article on using Enterprise Library caching block.

Comment: From what i've gathered, you cannot have cache expire in less than 2 minutes. That's way too long for me.

Comment: @Nicolai Where did you hear that? As far as I'm aware you could happily have a cache expiring every millisecond in Enterprise Library (wouldn't be a very effective cache of course!!)

Comment: yea, but the blog.stackoverflow article links to a different article (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12117/Simulate-a-Windows-Service-using-ASP-NET-to-run-sc), and it says that no matter how low you set the cache expire, it will not expire in less than 2 minutes.

Comment: @Nicolai The article you point to is talking about the inbuilt ASP.NET Caching, which is a different technology to Enterprise Library Caching. As far as I'm aware, EL Caching has **no** minimum expiry time.